# Best way to add colourful example code in html

Tags: html

I want to add the example codes in html page with various programming languages languages.

```
<div class="example-cpp">
     #include <iostream> 
     using namespace std; 
     int main () { 
        for( ; ; ) { 
           printf("This loop will run forever.\n"); 
        } 
        return 0;
     }
</div>
```

I want to show this with colourful font without separate style.
Like following example
[image] 

Can you suggest the best way ?

Comment: Use an existing JavaScript library. Something like [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/), to name just one example.

Comment: or something like https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) and [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) are good.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this and use it:

https://codemirror.net/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Then again, the question itself is considered off-topic...

Comment: i have to put it in the comment?

Comment: Instead of just linking some libraries or tools, you could instead explain how the task can generally be achieved. Satish Saini kind of did this by at least explaining that this is possible server-side and client-side. Anyway, don't bother. The question is off-topic *and* a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this client side and server side, both.

On client side, [SyntaxHighligher](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) can help you.

Server-side solutions tend to be more flexible, especially in the way of defining new languages and configuring how they are highlighted (e.g. colors used). [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/), which is a PHP solution with a moderately nice plugin for Wordpress.